# StreamBuilder on SidebarItems macos_ui

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get my sidebar populated by elements present in Firebase Firestore. I'm using a stream builder, but even if there's a document in my collection, I didn't get any sidebar item. This is my code

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> tasksStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users/$uid/tasks')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: tasksStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const ProgressCircle(
            value: null,
          );
        }
        return MacosWindow(
          child: MacosScaffold(
            children: [
              ContentArea(
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
                  return Center(
                    // Some code
                  );
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          sidebar: Sidebar(
            maxWidth: 400,
            minWidth: 200,
            builder: (context, controller) {
              return SidebarItems(
                  currentIndex: itemIndex,
                  onChanged: (i) => setState(() => itemIndex = i),
                  scrollController: controller,
                  items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return SidebarItem(
                      label: Text(
                        data['descrizione'],
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList()
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Am i missing something? I am using [macos_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/macos_ui) package

Comment: Can you verify that firestore is returning elements to print on the sidebarItems?

Comment: Yes and nothing is printed. I now get this error every time:

FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.)

And this happens only if I run my app with macos emulator. If I run it in iOS emulator all works well.

Comment: From what I understand the emulator is supposed to mimic the OS the behaviour as close as it can, it sounds like there might be internal issues with the macos_ui and the macos emulator not getting along.

Comment: Hi @HipsterCat, are you still having trouble with this issue? If so, would you mind filing an issue on the GitHub so I can help you further? I’ll of course provide an answer on this post as well in such a case. Cheers!